# How can I uninstall Sublime Text 3 from Windows 10?

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I uninstall Sublime Text 3 from Windows 10?
How i done it. This is the answer for help another people.

I tried to remove SUBLIME text 3, since some errors appear on each startup.
After clearing and reinstalling, the error reappears.
I searched for answer in google but did not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is what I did, it helped me.

1. Open sublime
2. In top menu choose:
   Preferences > Browse Pachages

   - The new explorer window will open with this path:

   #### C:\Users...you_name...\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages
3. Close sublime, but don`t close explorer window
4. Delete all folders inside this Packages folder
5. Uninstall sublime as you would do with any other Windows program using Programs and Features
6. Reinstall sumlime, if you want. Be happy. Now it is virgin clear.

Comment: Just for clarity, unless you are afraid that your hard drive is corrupting your files, you don't need to uninstall and reinstall Sublime to clear state; uninstalling does nothing to the data folder where your settings and packages are stored. Just cleaning that folder and restarting is enough to go back to a pristine state.